# How to setup NLB and ARR in server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nlb, arr

I'm in charge of deploying a web application.  I don't have a hardware load balancer to use.  So I thought I could use NLB+ARR.  Need to use ARR because my team needs to be able to take one of the 2 applications offline for matinenance and not have it time out for the user.  Is this possible to get NLB+ARR working together?  The design I'm thinking of is

fw->NLB(vip)-->ARR->web-app1, web-app2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, NLB and ARR work fine. See this [MSFT article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/achieving-high-availability-and-scalability-arr-and-nlb).

In the smallest possible configuration, you will have 2 servers, each with NLB, ARR and the web server installed on BOTH boxes.

Comment: I was actually just reading that article.  I can't use web server edition on R2 with NLB correct?

Comment: Follow Up question:  I have ARR and NLB working on my app server.  However I can't seem to get ARR to get the request.  I did a dummy request with ARR and forward it to google.com as the action and nothing happens.

Comment: Please post this as a new question